# How to symbolicate a kernel panic report on OSX?

Tags: macos, symbolicatecrash, symbolicate, kernel-extension

I want to know how can I symbolicate a kernel panic report (not a regular app crash report). I have an OSX app that a user claims caused a kernel panic. It doesn't install any kernel extension but a launch daemon. I have followed this link https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2063/_index.html but it only describes symbolication steps for the 3rd party kernel extension causing a kernel panic. How can I symbolicate the following panic report if I have not installed any kext? Any help will be appreciable.

```
Anonymous UUID:      DF6F780A-AA27-6D40-3441-F26F828C7096
Tue Oct 27 12:02:41 2015
*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 1 caller 0xffffff80111d6a9a): Kernel trap at 0xffffff80113cec30, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0x0000000100000057, CR3: 0x000000025eade116, CR4: 0x00000000001627e0
RAX: 0xffffff8037f9bdb0, RBX: 0xffffff803e68cd08, RCX: 0xffffff8037f9bdb0, RDX: 0xffffff8011910910
RSP: 0xffffff9236923890, RBP: 0xffffff9236923900, RSI: 0x0000000000000001, RDI: 0xffffff8011910910
R8:  0x0000000000000000, R9:  0x00000000000001f0, R10: 0xffffff80118ddb78, R11: 0x0000000000000000
R12: 0x00000000ffffffff, R13: 0x0000000000000000, R14: 0xffffff80117a1f7b, R15: 0xffffff8031c77a40
RFL: 0x0000000000010206, RIP: 0xffffff80113cec30, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000000
Fault CR2: 0x0000000100000057, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x1, PL: 0
Backtrace (CPU 1), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff9236923520 : 0xffffff80110e5357
0xffffff92369235a0 : 0xffffff80111d6a9a
0xffffff9236923780 : 0xffffff80111f4093
0xffffff92369237a0 : 0xffffff80113cec30
0xffffff9236923900 : 0xffffff80113d0229
0xffffff9236923920 : 0xffffff801140edc7
0xffffff9236923a40 : 0xffffff801140c838
0xffffff9236923ad0 : 0xffffff801135bdac
0xffffff9236923ba0 : 0xffffff801135bfff
0xffffff9236923bd0 : 0xffffff801139912d
0xffffff9236923d80 : 0xffffff80113983fd
0xffffff9236923da0 : 0xffffff8011596f61
0xffffff9236923de0 : 0xffffff80115f0ebc
0xffffff9236923e30 : 0xffffff80115f13ea
0xffffff9236923e50 : 0xffffff801158a610
0xffffff9236923ec0 : 0xffffff8011586140
0xffffff9236923f20 : 0xffffff801158a2b4
0xffffff9236923f60 : 0xffffff801162ace1
0xffffff9236923fb0 : 0xffffff80111f4896

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: MyApp
Mac OS version:
15A284
 Kernel version:
 Darwin Kernel Version 15.0.0: Wed Aug 26 16:57:32 PDT 2015; root:xnu-  3247.1.106~1/RELEASE_X86_64
 Kernel UUID: 37BC582F-8BF4-3F65-AFBB-ECF792060C68
 Kernel slide:    0x0000000010e00000
 Kernel text base: 0xffffff8011000000
  __HIB  text base: 0xffffff8010f00000
System model name: MacBookPro11,3 (Mac-2BD1B31983FE1663)
System uptime in nanoseconds: 48947258824078
last loaded kext at 46570627969383: com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver 124 (addr 0xffffff7f940e6000, size 20480)
last unloaded kext at 48111600364863: com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver 124 (addr 0xffffff7f940e6000, size 12288)
loaded kexts:
com.apple.nke.rvi 2.0.0
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 3.0.0
com.apple.filesystems.afpfs 11.0
com.apple.nke.asp-tcp 8.0.0
...
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OS X kernel panic diagnostics. How to translate backtrace addresses](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35334335/os-x-kernel-panic-diagnostics-how-to-translate-backtrace-addresses)